# OpenLayers 3 initial extent

Tags: openlayers

I know that ol3 view accepts center and zoom parameters to properly position the view. Is there a way to initialy render map that fits to provided extent [xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax]?

If no how to calculate proper zoom level that would fit to provided extent?

I know that there is fit method defined in view but that would require the map to be rendered and then zoomed.

Comment: Hey, did you find ?

Comment: No. I ended up listening to map being rendered and then fitting to bounds. Something like this `map.getView().fit(bounds, map.getSize());`

Comment: I did the same. I was afraid to see the map then the extent, but actually you can't see the transition so it's cool. Thanks again